# Can I install Oracle developer tools and use Oracle 10g?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, oracle

I just installed the latest version of Oracle developer tools and couldn't install it in my 10g home directory because you can only do that if your home is 11g. Now when I'm in VS2008, create a new connection and test it. It doesn't connect because I'm assuming it can't find my tsnames.ora since it's located under my 10g home.

Any way I can use the developer tools to use my 10g home directory?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I uninstalled my previous version and installed [this](http://download.oracle.com/otn/other/ole-oo4o/ODTwithODAC1020221.exe). Instead of installing it in a new directory I chose my current 10g installation direcvtory (C:\oracle\ora102). This now works because the installer is for Oracle 10g and that is what I have on my computer. I opened VS2008, added new data onnection, right-clicked my data connection and changed the view to "User Objects" (Change View -> User Objects). I can now see all tables.

Answer (score 1):

When I have multiple Oracle homes on my systems I prefer to set the environment variable TNS_ADMIN to the directory where my "master" tnsnames.ora file lives. This environment variable tells all Oracle products where to find the networking files, including sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora. In your case you would want <10ghome>\network\admin.